# Dataset: Car types by country

Tags: data-request, transportation, global

I am looking for a free dataset that shows the number of car types sold/in use in every country.

For example:

Italy: SUV: 2.500.000
          Sedan: 3.00.000
          ...
Spain: SUV: 3.500.000
            Sedan: 4.00.000
         ...

I just found datasets about cars manufactured in countries.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the OpenData site

Comment: Ok, I did not know this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a global dataset/database showing it per type.

I know the data for the Netherlands can be found [here](http://statline.cbs.nl/StatWeb/publication/?DM=SLNL&PA=82044NED&D1=a&D2=a&D3=10-13&VW=T) at the CBS (national statistics bureau).

Global data without types can be found in the [list of countries by vehicles per capita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_vehicles_per_capita) on Wikipedia, the references there (especially nr. 1) might help you out.